# Proving an inner product in $\mathbb{C}_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: convolution, normed-spaces

Let $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle : \mathbb{C}_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathbb{C}_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $$\langle f,g\rangle  := - \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) g(y) |x-y| dx dy$$

Show that the function ⟨·,·⟩ above defines an inner product over functions in $\mathbb{C}_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ that
integrate to zero over $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to simply the integral as $$\langle f,g\rangle  := - \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\ ( g(x) *|x|)\ dx$$

I am not able prove the properties of the inner product. Can someone please help me out by giving a small hint?

Comment: Your task is to prove that it is an inner product, not a norm. Perhaps that is tripping you up.

Comment: What properties aren't you able to prove?

Comment: Like $<f,f> \geq 0$. I just need to have a look what logic is behind this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Parseval-Plancherel and the convolution theorem to express $\langle f,g\rangle $ in term of $\hat{f},\hat{g}$, find the Fourier transform of $|x|$ (its second derivative is $2\delta$), use the analyticity of $\hat{f}\hat{g}$ and that it has a double zero to obtain a simple formula for $\langle f,g\rangle $ making it obvious that it is an inner product.

Comment: What do you mean by analyticity of $f^ g^$?

Comment: The Fourier transform of a $C^\infty_c$ function is entire (= to its Taylor series everywhere) but this point will make sense only if you know the Fourier transform of the distribution $|x|$

Comment: $$\langle f,g\rangle  := - \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\ ( g(x) *|x|)\ dx = - \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(f) F(g) F(|x|) =- \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(f)F(g)(\frac{-1}{2 \pi^2 k^2}) dk $$. Is that what you mean? @reuns

Comment: Yes. But the Fourier transform of $|x|$ is $pf(-1/2\pi^2 k^2)$ (finite part, a generalization of the principal value, this is because $\int_R \hat{\phi}(k) /2\pi^2 k^2dk $ diverges when $\hat{\phi}(0)\ne 0$) and this subtlety disappears precisely because $\int_R f(x)dx=\int_R g(x)dx=0$

Comment: How to generalise the formula from here?

Comment: To generalize what ? You are saying you never heard about such finite part distributions ?

Comment: Generalising the simple formula for <f,g>?